# Setting up redirects in Azure AD B2C (Updating Password & Logging Out)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on a website that is using a CMS and is authenticating against Azure AD B2C.  When a user update's their password, they are redirected to a page not found.  I'm not sure where to adjust the setting in Azure to fix this.  Could someone help me out?

It also appears that a similar issue is when users logout.

Answer (score 1):

First, add `Redirect URIs` and `Logout URL` of your application in the portal. The redirect URI is the endpoint to which the user is sent by the authorization server (Azure AD B2C, in this case) after completing its interaction with the user, and to which an access token or authorization code is sent upon successful authorization. The logout URL is used when users logout.

[image]

The Reply URL in `Run user flow` is redirect URI of the previous step. You could use this to test whether your URI settings work.

[image]

Then add redirect settings in your code. Change the URIs to the same URIs you set before.
For example, like [this](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS/blob/master/config.js#L19) in config.js. You could refer to the [code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples) for more information.